# maven shows up some modules marked as "unnamed"

Tags: maven-2

I'm working with maven in a multi module project and it works fine. But when it starts it refers to some projects as unnamed. Why does this happen, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In every sub module, simply specify a `<name>`:

```
<project>
    ...
    <name>My project</name>
    ...
```

This `name` will then be used by the Reactor to display the build order of the modules.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give a name entry in every module you use. That should help. May be you can post your pom...if it isn't the problem.

```
<name>Entry</name>
```